# Variable between two different definitions

Tags: python, variables

I want to call var d from b(). but I get this error. I have heard that you can have global variables which I tried but with no success.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user2/Desktop/def.py", line 9, in <module>
    a()
  File "C:/Users/user2/Desktop/def.py", line 3, in a
    if d == 0:
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

**Code:**

```
def a():
    if d == 0:
        print(correct)
    else:
        print (not correct)
def b():
    d = 0

a()
```

Comment: you have not defined `d` in function `a()` and if you want to use `d` from function `b()` you have to return `d`

Comment: and what the variable "d" should mean?

Comment: `print(correct)` and `print(not correct)` are also invalid syntax, it should be a string - `print('correct')` and so on

Comment: please consider reading [the basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable outside the function and it should work. Although it is better to pass as argument.

```
d=0
correct="It is correct"
notcorrect="It is not correct"

def a():
    if d == 0:
        print(correct)
    else:
        print(notcorrect)

a()
```

Comment: but note, that `b()` is never called and can be removed from the code..

Comment: Yes, you are right @sarbot. I just forgot to remove it when copy-pasting the code from Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables of a "parent" scope, even if it's better to pass them to the method. Your function `b()` is never called in your example. And definitions in a function are just defined for this functions or functions called from there.

I would recommend you to read about scopes:
https://pythonspot.com/scope/ (there are tons of other tutorials out there, just use your search engine ;))

what you could do:

```py
d = 0
a()  # correct
```

what you could do as well:

```py
def b():
   d = 0
   a()

b()  # correct
```

but what you SHOULD do is probably something like:

```py
def b():
  d = 0
  return d

def a(d):
  ...

a(b())  # correct
```

global variables exist in python, but especially for beginners it often seems to be an easy solution, but as soon as your code grows this can become very complex if not used carefully.. understanding scopes of variables and how to pass them into other functions is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The code will definitely show an error because the variables created within the function are for that function only called local variables, and the variable created outside the function are called global variables.

hence,

1. you simply have to create the variable outside the function globally then it will not shows error.

```py
def a(d):
    if d == 0:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print ("not correct")
#################
a(0)
```

2. or else you can use inbuilt function `global()` if you want to use the variable inside the different functions.
   and make sure you have the functions as well.